# How to make successive method calls with less repetitive code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here's an example from HockeyApp that generates the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().configureWithIdentifier(API_KEY)
    BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().disableCrashManager = true
    BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().startManager()
    BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager().authenticator.authenticateInstallation()

    return true
}
```

Notice the repetition of `BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager()` in each call. I'm looking for a syntax that does something like (pseudo code):

```
with BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager() do {
    .configureWithIdentifier(API_KEY)
    .disableCrashManager = true
    .startManager()
    .authenticator.authenticateInstallation()
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Swift?

*Edit:* After writing this question I noticed that [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) is using "chainable methods" , which actually is originally what I was looking for. This allows a neat syntax, as follows (code from http://nshipster.com/alamofire/):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
         .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                     println(request)
                     println(response)
                     println(error)
                   }
```

To use the corresponding syntax with HockeyApp would require modifying the `BITHockeyManager` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that something like

```
with BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager() do {
    .configureWithIdentifier(API_KEY)
    .disableCrashManager = true
    // ...
}
```

is possible in Swift, but what you *could* do is to define a generic function

```
func with<T>(item : T, closure : T -> Void) {
    closure(item)
}
```

which simply calls the closure with the given item as the argument,
and then take advantage of the "trailing closure syntax" and "shorthand argument name" `$0`:

```
with( BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager() ) {
    $0.configureWithIdentifier(API_KEY)
    $0.disableCrashManager = true
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good solution but I think this does not make the code more readable and maintainable... :-)

Comment: Well, it is just a suggestion and meant as a reply to *"Is there a syntax to get rid of defining the `manager`?"*, which was originally in the question and later removed.

Comment: It's a good solution, and also answers the modified question.

Comment: ... which makes me wonder if you can do the same with a prefix operator.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, fully agreed. It is just my opinion that I would not choose that way due to the bad readabilty of the code. The solution itself is very good!

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct, as I haven't found a better way to do implement what I asked. However, my answer (the standard way) would be the actual way to do it to maintain readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the following approach, which is a little bit shorter, but still requires repetition of the variable `manager`:

```
let manager = BITHockeyManager.sharedHockeyManager()
manager.configureWithIdentifier(API_KEY)
manager.disableCrashManager = true
manager.startManager()
manager.authenticator.authenticateInstallation()
```

Comment: I guess this is the best you can get. I'd do it the same way.